# Cygwin gcc no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

May I know what this error means and how I may get around it? I'm sure gcc is installed correctly so I'm not sure what is the cause of this problem. The file is also in the same directory as Cygwin.

This error pops up even after reinstalling and updating, I ran the setup exe 3 times but the same issue persists.

```
$ gcc -g -o lab1 lab1.c
cc1: fatal error: lab1.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Because your file argument does not specify a path, `gcc` will be looking in the current working directory. If you perform a `ls lab1.c` here, do you see any results? If not, you're in the wrong directory.